# Is a Wildcard cert better for Exchange DR than a SAN cert?

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013, disaster-recovery, outlook-2013, mirror-site

I'm reading [this blog article about the logic of Autodiscover,](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2008/09/29/3406352.aspx) and I hope I'm misreading it.

The problem I have is that it appears that the Autodiscover process will inspect the SUBJECT of a certificate and use that to determine the most appropriate site for a CAS connection base on the `set-outlookprovider` setting.

**Question**

Since outlook providers define a global setting, one that is used by all sites, and it has an impact on Autodiscover... what certificate **AND** outlook provider setting should I have to have a resilient client profile w.r.t. Autodiscover and the certificate subject name that is published in the remote site?

Should the subject name be *.company.com?  Or have a SAN name?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Providers no longer used in Exchange 2013.
Having wildcard cert enables you to simplify naming deployment across any geographical allocation very easily, of cause it's not the only option. At the end SAN limits you to the name in the cert, which requires you to implement other load-balancing and high-availability solution, which complicates deployment.